# Mount external sdcard after upgrade to Jelly Bean 4.2.2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, external-sd, 4.2-jelly-bean

Yesterday I installed a custom rom on my Samsung Galaxy S2. Before I had ICS 4.0.3 installed. Now my external sdcard does not mount automatically on the phone. How can I get this working?

Comment: Won't mount where -- on your device, or on your PC? Any error messages? Please give a few more details, it's hard to help without them :)

Comment: Thanks. I've clarified the question. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: OK, first part done. Second part was the "error messages". Can you e.g. get a grep on some `logcat` (e.g. using `adb logcat` from your PC; if you don't have the SDK installed on the latter, see e.g. [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for an "easy way")? If you cannot find your way through those log messages, you could e.g. upload them to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and link from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the location or link to the external sdcard has moved from /sdcard/external_sd to /extSdCard, while the /sdcard/external_sd was blank. So I thought that the card was not mounted, but in fact it was.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of sdcards are formatted as ExFAT (extended FAT32 - which is better than FAT32 in a number of aspects for flash media, including support for larger than 4GB files). Unfortunately, this is a licensed and proprietary technology and custom ROMs can't legally include support. If you have a card reader for your computer, you can use that to back up the contents of your sdcard. Then you can right click on the drive in My Computer and select format. Select FAT32 and let it do its thing. When it is finished, copy the contents back to the drive and put it back in your phone.

If you don't have access to a card reader, then you will either need to use another phone to back up your content on the card, or possibly, see if you can still enable USB Mass Storage in recovery (most likely under the Mounts and Storage menu depending on the recovery used). If you can't do either, then you can just format the sdcard from within recovery, which will put the filesystem to standard FAT32 and make it readable in your custom ROM, although, this will erase all the content on the card.